# Return combined expression

Tags: c#

Following example gives me an error

```
public Func<double> ReturnExpression(Func<double> a, Func<double> b)
        {
            return () => a * b;
        }
```

what is wrong with that ? If I know that a returns double, and b also, why I can't return new expression combined from results of a and b ?

Error I have : `can't applay operand * to operands of type Func<double> and Func<double>`

Comment: They're functions, so you need to call them like functions: `a() * b()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a and b are functions. You need to do this:

```
public Func<double> ReturnExpression(Func<double> a, Func<double> b)
        {
            return () => a() * b();
        }
```

Syntax is invalid in the OP, but you get the idea.